# Django user followers ajax issue

Tags: django, ajax, django-templates

I have built user folloing functionality with Ajax, so a user can follow/unfollow another user. The problem is that when I click "follow" button nothing happens in the frontend. I mean text doesn't change to "Unfollow", as it should be and number of followers does not change too. If reload the page, it is fine - a follower is added. Then if I click "Unfollow" button everything works fine - Ajax request is ok, and in db a follower is deleted. I found out, that the problem happens, because when pushing the "Follow" button and send a Post request, the response code is 500 (Internal Server Error). With "Unfollow" it works fine and the request is 200. I spent a lot of time struggling with this. Any help appriciated.

Bellow is the code.

**The user model and the model for following functionality:**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.conf import settings
    
    from .managers import CustomUserManager
    from team.models import Team
    
    
    
    class Contact(models.Model):
        user_from = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser',
                                      related_name='rel_from_set',
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        user_to = models.ForeignKey('CustomUser',
                                    related_name='rel_to_set',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                       db_index=True)
    
        class Meta:
            ordering = ('-created',)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from,
                                          self.user_to)
    
    
    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        username = None
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
        team = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        profile_img = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
        following = models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False)
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
        objects = CustomUserManager()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
    
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('user-detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

**views.py file:**

````
```
@ajax_required
@require_POST
@login_required
def user_follow(request):
    user_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if user_id and action:
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=user_id)
            if action == 'follow':
                Contact.objects.get_or_create(user_from=request.user,
                                              user_to=user)
                create_action(request.user, 'is following', user)
            else:
                Contact.objects.filter(user_from=request.user,
                                       user_to=user).delete()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
    return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
````

**urls.py :**

```
    urlpatterns = [
        
        path('users/follow/', views.user_follow, name='user_follow'),
    ...another urls...
    ]
```

**The the follow/unfollow button, displayed in the html:**

```
       {% with total_followers=user.followers.count %}
       <span class="count-f">
         <span class="total-f">{{ total_followers }}</span>
         follower{{ total_followers|pluralize }}
       </span>
       <a href="#" data-id="{{ user.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{% endif %}follow" class="follow button">
         {% if request.user not in user.followers.all %}
           Follow
         {% else %}
           Unfollow
         {% endif %}
       </a>
       
     {% endwith %}
```

**And in the same html file the ajax code:**

```
    {% block domready %}
       $('a.follow').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const $clickedFollowButton = $( this );
        
        $.post('{% url "user_follow" %}',
          {
            id: $clickedFollowButton.data('id'),
            action: $clickedFollowButton.data('action')
          },
          function(data){
            if (data['status'] == 'ok') {
              var previous_action = $clickedFollowButton.data('action');
    
              // toggle data-action
              $clickedFollowButton.data('action', previous_action == 'follow' ? 'unfollow' : 'follow');
              
              // toggle link text
              $clickedFollowButton.text(previous_action == 'follow' ? 'Unfollow-ha-ha' : 'Follow');
    
              // update total followers
              const $totalFollowers = $clickedFollowButton.prev('span.count-f').children('.total-f');
              var previous_followers = parseInt(
                $('span.count-f .total-f').text());
              
               $totalFollowers.text(previous_action == 'follow' ? previous_followers + 1 : previous_followers - 1);
               
               console.log(previous_action);
           
            }
          }
        );
      });  
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem is. The error I get was caused of that line of code in the view function:

```
    create_action(request.user, 'is following', user)
```

I used nonexisting function create_action. After deleting it everthing works fine.